# R vcd::mosaic overlapping labels

Tags: r, plot, mosaic-plot, vcd

I'm generating a mosaic plot with `vcd::mosaic`. But the text of the factors I was given are very long (cutting them is not an option, and with so many instances, introducing `\n` seems daunting), so there's an overlap in the texts, and I haven't been able to force the labels to go perpendicular to the axis.

This is what I'm trying:

```
a <- data.frame(x=sample(LETTERS[1:4],16,replace = TRUE), 
                y=rep(paste("very long label here at number", 1:4, paste=" "), 4))
mosaic(y ~ x, data= a, las= 2)
```

but this is what I get:
[image]

I've also tryed `par(las= 2)` and `par(las= 3)` but none of those is able to force them into vertical alignment (`las= 2` works well with `mosaicplot`, though. It's like `vcd::mosaic` overrides `las` either as a given parameter or as a default-set in `par`. I've played also with `par(mar)`, but the labels are long enough to fool that workaround.

What can I do to get readable labels?

**########## EDIT TO ADD: ##########**

I've also tried this, to no avail:

```
mosaic(y ~ x, data= a, labeling_list= list(gp_text= gpar(las= 2)))
```

and

```
mosaic(y ~ x, data= a, labeling_list= list(rot_labels = c(0,90,0,0)))
  # Actually placed the "90" in the 4 positions

mosaic(y ~ x, data= a, labeling_list= list(rot_varnames = c(0,90,0,0)))
```

Comment: You could try with `rep(paste("very long label\n here at number\n", 1:4, paste=" "), 4)`, if it fits your requirement.

Comment: Pascal, thanks for your comment, but as I stated in the question the data is a lot more (and a lot more complex) than the reproducible example, so inputting `\n` will be very cumbersome. I'd like to know how to rotate the labels :'(

Comment: I don't think rotating the labels is a good solution.

Comment: @Pascal some of the labels in the mosaic plot have very small areas, which mean they're quite cramped to the sides. It doesn't matter if I split each string at 5 characters, they'll be one on top of the other. I understand you don't like rotating the labels, but could you show me how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry, but you misinterpret what I am saying.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally found it! Key searching docs:

```
?labelings
?labeling_border
```

In order to rotate the labels

```
mosaic(y ~ x, 
       data= a, 
       labeling= labeling_border(rot_labels = c(90,0,0,0), 
                                 just_labels = c("left", 
                                                 "center", 
                                                 "center", 
                                                 "center")))
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
+ theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-25, hjust= .1))
```

it will rotate labels for 25 degrees (you can just copy and paste)

Comment: I don't understand -- cut and paste this to where?

Comment: This comment is relevant to the ggplot ecosystem, but vcd uses grid graphics (and thus this information isn't applicable to vcd).