# Is there a way to move labels up on a sieve plot in order to make the graphs look cleaner?

Tags: r, sieve, floating-labels

I am working on a research project and I am trying to show my boss some clean graphs that can be put into a project. I made this sieve plot and I can't figure out 1. How to rotate the x-axis labels and make pull them off the graph and 2. How to move up the y-axis labels that are overlapping the top of the graph as well.

I have tried to rotate the labels and it still overlaps the graph.

```
library(vcd)
library(vcdExtra)
All <- matrix(c(924,139,67,42, 115,66,61,22, 40,37,51,45, 33,19,30,57), 4, 4)
dimnames(All) <- list(Drinking2002 =c("Rare","Light","Moderate","Heavy"), Drinking2014 =c("Rare","Light","Moderate","Heavy"))
All <- as.table(All)
sieve(All, shade = TRUE, labeling = labeling_values, gp_text = gpar(fontface = 2), rot_labels = c(top = 45))
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

1) `rot_labels = c(left = #, top = #)` to rotate labels 
2) `offset_labels = c(#, #, #, #) to adjust the distance from the axis.

```
sieve(All, shade = TRUE, labeling = labeling_values, 
      gp_text = gpar(fontface = 2), 
      rot_labels = c(top = 45, left = 0), 
      offset_labels = c(0.6, 0, 0, 1)
      )
```

[image]

Or

```
sieve(All, shade = TRUE, labeling = labeling_values, 
      gp_text = gpar(fontface = 2), 
      rot_labels = c(top = 0, left = 0), 
      offset_labels = c(0.6, 0, 0, 1)
      )
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to move the axis titles up, Like the Drinking2014? On my markdown I keep having troubles with rare hitting the Drinking2014 label

Comment: yes, try `offset_varnames = c(0.5, 0, 0, 0.5)`. Adjust values to see if  it is possible to fit your markdown.

Comment: Just think of alternatives. If variable names keep causing troubles, you could try to move them inside: `offset_varnames = c(-3, 0, 0, -3)`, or even remove them completely: `varnames = FALSE`, and explain them in the title or elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Extending based on the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399772/r-vcdmosaic-overlapping-labels) for mosaic plot.

```
sieve(All, shade = TRUE, 
     labeling = labeling_border(rot_labels = c(30,0,0,30),just_labels = c("left","right","right","right")), 
     gp_text = gpar(fontface = 2), 
     rot_labels = c(top = 45))
```

You can play around with `c(30,0,0,30)` to change the degree of rotation and with `c("left","right","right","right")` for label alignment. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**: Added screenshots

Output 1:

Using `just_labels = c("left","right","right","right")`
[image]

Output 2:

Using `just_labels = c("left","right","right","left")`

[image]

Comment: what does the just_labels = c("left","right","right","right") do?

Comment: Edited my answer. They are used to align the labels in the plot.

Comment: Is there a way to move the axis titles up, Like the Drinking2014? On my markdown I keep having troubles with rare hitting the Drinking2014 label

Comment: Could you add a screenshot?